# How can I make javascript change main div depending on what thumbnail is clicked?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following items laid out in static blocks:

```
<div class="twentytwenty-wrapper twentytwenty-horizontal">
    <div class="image-compare-set twentytwenty-container image-compare-1 current-slider"></div>
</div>
<div class="twentytwenty-wrapper twentytwenty-horizontal">
    <div class="image-compare-set twentytwenty-container image-compare-2 current-slider"></div>
</div>
<div class="twentytwenty-wrapper twentytwenty-horizontal">
    <div class="image-compare-set twentytwenty-container image-compare-3 current-slider"></div>
</div>
<div class="twentytwenty-wrapper twentytwenty-horizontal">
    <div class="image-compare-set twentytwenty-container image-compare-4 current-slider"></div>
</div>
```

Along with a thumbnail navigation block below:

```
<div class="image-compare-nav owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="owl-wrapper">
        <div class="owl-item">
            <a href="#" rel="image-compare-1" class="item"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="owl-item">
            <a href="#" rel="image-compare-2" class="item"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="owl-item">
            <a href="#" rel="image-compare-3" class="item"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="owl-item">
            <a href="#" rel="image-compare-4" class="item"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

At the moment, all of the main twentytwenty blocks appear underneath each other, but what I want to happen is that only the first one is displayed, and whena thumbnail is clicked, the relating slider div, is shown in it's place.

It's important that as each thumbnail is clicked, the slider changes from the old one, to the new one.

So far I've got this http://jsfiddle.net/96rq4vet/2/ but, when the thumbnails are clicked, the new div isn't showing up, they're staying hidden.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I'm getting closer with this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/96rq4vet/3/ however, I can't get only the first main div to show at first. I tried adding `style:display:none;` to the second-fourth one, but that doesn't make them show when the thumbnails are clicked.

Any ideas?

Comment: Need to see your jQuery for the slick slider init.

Comment: use [jQuery attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to both get and set `src`

Comment: @Red2678 Have updated my question.

Comment: @charlietfl Can you please explain this, where to use it, and what it will do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using classes you could use `data` attributes. You can then grab the `data` attribute of the thumb that is clicked in order to associate it with the data attribute of the image you want to display.

Something like this:

```
<div class="twentytwenty-container" data-image-num="1">
    <img />
</div>

<div class="imageSet" data-image-num="1">
    <img />
</div>


$('.imageSet').click(function() {
    var imageNum = $(this).attr('data-image-num');
    $('.twentytwenty-container[data-image-num="' + imageNum + '"]').show();
});
```

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pav5kq8m/)

Comment: I would recommend the use of `.data()` instead of `.attr()` in this case like: `$(this).data('image-num')`... Also, avoid the use of hyphenated key. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr

Comment: That looks interesting, but it's not removing the large div when another small one is loaded?

Comment: This code doesn't remove anything it just shows/hides an image depending on what thumbnail you click on.

Comment: Thanks, have updated my question to make it clearer what I'm after

Comment: I have created an added a jSFiddle that matches what i'm after. Would you be able to have a go at that, and create a fork?